# Why doesn't readlink return a null-terminated value?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, posix, system-calls, readlink

Both [The Single UNIX ® Specification, Version 2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/readlink.html) (1997) and [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readlink.html) (2004) require that `readlink` would not place a null-terminated value in `buffer`:

> #### APPLICATION USAGE
>
> Conforming applications should not assume that the returned contents of the symbolic link are null-terminated.

What are the considerations in not null-terminating `buffer`? Couldn't it pose a security risk when `readlink` isn't properly used?

Comment: Anything can be a security risk when not properly used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the considerations in not null-terminating buffer?

As indicated by the documentation, portability. Most probably there exists(-ed?) wide used implementations of `readlink` that do not null-terminate the buffer.

> Couldn't it pose a security risk when readlink isn't properly used?

Every piece of bad code that uses something not properly I guess poses a security risk. The programmer is responsible for writing good code that has no security risks. The examples section of posix page shows the proper usage of `readlink`.

Answer (score 0):

I just read your links.

A simple way to make this safe to use is to write a zero into the last buffer position when the function returns. Use the returned size.

You should double check that the returned size value is not -1 and is always less than the buffer length. If it was equal then it was truncated (probably).